# Bootstrap selectpicker, after the label input does not wrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've the problem with selectpicker. When I use it, input not wrap.

For exemple:

```
 <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
 <label for="sesso">Sesso dei partecipanti</label>
 <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="sesso" id="sesso">
 <option value="" disabled="" selected="selected" class="hide-option">Seleziona</option>
<option value="M">Maschile</option>
 <option value="F">Femminile</option>
<option value="X">Misto</option>
</select>                            
</div>
```

without selectpicker input wrap after the label tag:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
<label for="numero_partecipanti">Numero Partecipanti</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numero_partecipanti" id="numero_partecipanti">
</div>
```

this is the url with complete html:
http://www.mytennishouse.com/home/test.php